# React: Multiplying state then setting it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am working on transforming an excel spreadsheet into a webapp. One issue I have is how to update the "targetLevel" value which is a nested child. How Would I make the multiplication possible for this state? ex: targetLevel = averagePolicy * appsPerWeek * productionWeeks

(there are other groupings of values in state not shown, that is why it is nested)

```
this.state = {
   personalValues: [
     {targetLevel: 0},
     {firstCommission: 90    },
     {cancels: 0},
     {averagePolicy: 0},
     {productionWeeks: 0},
     {presentationsPW: 0},
     {closing: 0},
     {appsPerWeek: 0}
   ]
```

The function i tried does not get the value:(onBlur)

```
changeValues(event){

this.setState(()=> {
  const total = this.state.personalValues[3]['averagePolicy'] * this.state.personalValues[7]['appsPerWeek'] * this.state.personalValues[4]['productionWeeks'];
  return {
    personalValues: [
      targetLevel: total
    ]
  }
});
```

}

The form change method(onChange)

```
handleFormChange(event){
  this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
```

I included a gif for clarification

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/1AIw43dsese4XyvEJR)

Comment: When is changeValues called?

Comment: ChangeValues is called onBlur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your state is getting mutated and new state assignment seems to be incorrect. Please try the following code.

```
const total = this.state.personalValues[3]['averagePolicy'] * this.state.personalValues[7]['appsPerWeek'] * this.state.personalValues[4]['productionWeeks'];
const newStateValue = [...this.state.personalValues];
newStateValue[0] = {targetLevel: total};
return {
    personalValues: newStateValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like below to override the value of targetLevel

```
changeValues(event){
  const total = this.state.personalValues[3]['averagePolicy'] * this.state.personalValues[7]['appsPerWeek'] * this.state.personalValues[4]['productionWeeks'];
  this.setState(prevState => ({
      personalValues: prevState.personalValues.map(
      obj => Object.assign(obj, { targetLevel: total }));
  }));  
}
```